# Lazzy Listbox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using the very popular LazyListBox from Peter Torr.

```
<lazy:LazyListBox x:name="lazy"> // cause error
    <lazy:LazyListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </lazy:LazyListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <lazy:LazyListBox.LoadedItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </lazy:LazyListBox.LoadedItemTemplate> </lazy:LazyListBox>
```

It gives me an error when i assigned name to listbox.

```
The type 'UIExtensionMethods.ISupportOffsetChanges' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'UIExtensionMethods, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. D:\projectEG\Size4u(day1)\Size4u\Size4u\obj\Debug\Size4uView\HomePage.g.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the reference to the dll in the project.
In Visual studio project explorer search for "References" and Add Reference.. Now i'm at phone so i don't remember the names bur search for references list.

Comment: Thanks Marco.I missed to add reference

Comment: Accept this answer if everything is ok ;)

Comment: I have got the same error, which reference i need to add, and from where i can get the reference dll.